# Why $wpdb works on localhost but it is not working on server

Tags: wordpress, server, localhost, post-meta, meta-query

I am building a plugin in WordPress and $wpdb queries works on local, but when I upload the code to the server it doesn't work.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<?php 

global $wpdb;

$resultado = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='keywords'",
        OBJECT
    )
);

$keywords = implode(',', array_column($resultado, "meta_value"));

?>
```

Comment: Two observations: 1) If you're not passing variables to the query you don't really need to use the [prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) method at all; and 2) `OBJECT` has to be passed to [get_results()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/), not to the `prepare()` method.

Comment: are you sure table name same on server `wp_postmeta` but sometime prefix might be different. Try something like `global $wpdb, $table_prefix;$table = $table_prefix . 'postmeta';`

Comment: now i tried with global ` $wpdb, $table_prefix;$table = $table_prefix . 'postmeta';` and change the query to ` $resultado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM $table WHERE meta_key='keywords'", OBJECT );` and this works on local but still not working on server